# Create website image programatically

Tags: php, javascript, python, ruby, phantomjs

When I look at social bookmarking website or web master tools, they have a screenshot of a website showing.

I would like to do the same thing.
How can I go about doing this? (I know they are not using iframe, but rather small thum nail size png file)

Is it possible to achieve this with javascript or do I need to use Windows or Mac OS that can take a screenshot from browser and somehow automate it?

I would like to achieve this goal with javascript or PHP, Python, Ruby.
(I read somewhere that phantomjs might be able to achieve this?)

Please give teach me how I can go about with this problem.

Comment: To the -1 guy. It's a valid question. Probably not the best presentation but still valid.

Comment: @tntu Well, there are at least 3 different, poorly expressed questions in there. As it stands it is overly broad and it is difficult to work out what it is being asked and then it appears to end with what can be interpreted as a 'gimme teh codez' statement. It may well be closed as Not A Real Question. Focusing on one issue and asking a precise question would help the OP get a good focused answer.

Comment: Apology for being vague. Will be more specific next time

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Screen-Capture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a server side programming language that has a webkit module.

Using that you could create a widget into a virtual display and load the site in that and get a screenshot made once it's done loading.

I have done something like this using python, qt, qt webkit and pyqt but did not take a screenshot.

**This might help:**

http://codescience.wordpress.com/2011/04/19/very-simple-web-browser-on-pyqt4-and-webkit/

Keep in mind that what you want is a bit different so just go to the point where you open the site in the widget and find a way to take the screenshot.

Also look into executing the app into a virtual display.

Comment: Anyone care to comment?

Comment: You probably got downvoted because this isn't really an answer, more of a woolly set of suggestions that may or may not lead the OP in the right direction. Answers on SO should be definite answers and more authorities than this. There is nothing wrong in helping like this, but it should be done in comments.